# XCBuild shows error while calling fastlane gym

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild, fastlane-gym

I have an app with multiple targets and try to configure fastlane's gym. Also, we use pretty extensively compiler flags in the app.

I get this error `FIXME: Implement XCBuild support for macros in overriding parameters with condition sets: DEVELOPMENT_TEAM[config=Release] = ***`.

The error appears after gym executes this xcodebuild command:
`set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Workspace.xcworkspace -scheme Scheme -xcconfig Config.xcconfig -sdk 'iphoneos14.5' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath archivePath.xcarchive archive | tee Myapp.log | xcpretty`

The app is native, no Ionic or ReactNative or any of that stuff.

Do you have any idea where does come from? Or how I can solve it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have condition sets in `Config.xcconfig`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH There is one for the signing like this ```CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[config=Release] = iPhone Distribution``` and it repeats for each config (release, staging, ...)

Comment: I think you don't need condition there, just set `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling upon this question, I found the solution in this [blog](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html). Quoting from the blogpost:

> Example:

```
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION_app = 15.3.9 // Application version number
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION_xctest = 1.0.0 // Unit Test version number

CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION_$(WRAPPER_EXTENSION))
```

where in my case `WRAPPER_EXTENSION` would be `CONFIGURATION` variable.